# SQL Server More Efficient Substring

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am running a query in SQL Server where I need to join two tables into one where the full name field matches the partial name field in another after apostrophes have been removed. For a code example the join is happening like this:

```
from [Data1]
right join [Data2]
    on replace([Data2].[PartialName], '''','')=Substring([Data1].[FullName],1,1+LEN(replace([Data2].[PartialName], '''','')))
```

And it works. But it takes what would be a 10 second execution if we just used where name=name and makes it take around 20 minutes. This is rather unacceptable in terms of run time so I was wondering if anyone had any more efficient alternatives to consider.

Btw Data 1 has about 800 lines and Data2 has about 1.6 million if it's relevant.

Edit: I've been told I need to give a bit more descriptive information. Basically in this example Data1 is a table from an outside source that contains a name field [FullName] which contains people's full names in the form of 'Last-Name , First-Name Middle-Name(s)' with any apostrophes removed (for example in the name O'Neil it would just be ONeil).
So an example would be 'ONeil , Sarah Conner'

Data2 contains a name field that has names in the form 'Last-Name , First-Name' Middle names are omitted and apostrophes are intact. So for example 'O'Neil , Sarah'

These tables need to be merged together on their name fields, hence the logic above.

Comment: How about adding a persisted computed column on the table that stores the `substring` value?

Comment: @DavidG what i was thinking, however, the expression on `[Data1].[FullName]` uses the length of `[Data2].[PartialName]`. To the OP: What is the logic behind that? This expression looks like it's much more removed that simply removing the apostrohe's from the name.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean a bit? Do you mean an additional column on the Data1 table that stores the trimmed down string? Because it needs to match the length of the string in Data2 so we wont know how much to shrink it by in advance.

Comment: @Larnu Oh blimey, I didn't even spot that.

Comment: @larnu Oh I see I was a little confusing up above.. the field from Data2 needs to be shrunk down to the size of the field from Data1... and this is the field from Data1 that needs the apostrophes removed, the field from Data2 already does not have them.

Comment: @Kron why are you trying to remove `'` characters anyway? What are you trying to do? Applying such functions on fields *guarantees* bad performance. The server has no way of knowing what the function results are so it *has* to scan the entire table. You'll have to explain what you are actually trying to do so people can help you find an alternative

Comment: @Kron right now you described how you tried solving the real problem `the field from Data2 needs to be shrunk down to the size of the field from Data1... and this is the field from Data1 that needs the apostrophes removed` why? What is the *real* matching logic? What does the data look like?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added an edit to the original post. Does that help?

Comment: I was just wondering - are apostrophes being removed because of perceived problems with them?  The 'problem' seems to be in building SQL though (if done wrongly).  The name O'nions is different from the name Onions though (My Mum's first boss, she reckons he added the apostrophe).  Just a thought, it may have been a mis-think.

Comment: @Kron you should clean up the data while loading it and convert it to the *same* format. As Cato explains though, you probably have a bug somewhere else. Otherwise you won't be able to process Irish names. `O`Neil` isn't `Oneil`. String comparisons are typically case-INsensitive as well, so `ONeil` will match `Oneil`

Comment: @Kron in any case *name matching* is complex. It just *can't* be done with simple replacements and direct comparisons. That's why SQL Server's ETL system, SSIS, has fuzzy matching and fuzzy lookup operators to calculate a confidence number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DavidG is right, a `PERSISTED` column is the way to go here. After drinking a little more coffee, I think you need a computed column and then `LIKE` in your `JOIN`. The `PERSISTED` column's SQL would be something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [Data2] ADD PartialName_na AS REPLACE(PartialName,'''','') PERSISTED;
```

You *may* want to add that to an index. Then your new (pseudo) SQL query would be:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Data2 D2
     LEFT JOIN Data1 D1 ON D1.FullName = D2.PartialName_na + '%';
```

There's no need to use `SUBSTRING`. `LIKE` will maintain SARGability here, it doesn't use a leading wildcard.

*Edit: Couple of notes. I used the `_na` suffix to stand for "No Apostrophe"; you can call the column whatever you want. I also changed the query from a `RIGHT JOIN` to a `LEFT JOIN`. Personally I feel that `LEFT JOIN`s are much easier to read, however, if you want to swap it back round, feel free.*

Comment: Good call I think, was going to have a deeper look at this but got called into a meeting.

Comment: I'll test this in a moment and get back to you. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: I notice that I am getting a strange error with this result.
At a simple test on the name 'Ashour , Khaled Saadeldin'

select * from [Data1]
where substring([FullName],1,15)='Ashour , Khaled' 
is finding the full name above just fine.

whereas:
select * from [Data1]
where [FullName]+'%' LIKE 'Ashour , Khaled' 
is not finding it.

Comment: "A strange error" @Kron ...?  Would you like to *share* that error? 

Comment: @Larnu Sorry I pressed 'enter' to go to a new line while typing and accidentally posted the message early XD

Comment: @Kron no, that won't work. Your Wildcard is on the wrong side of the expression. Look at my SQL, it's `[column1] LIKE [column2] + '%'`.You've channed the SQL to`[Column2] + '%' LIKE [Column1]`, which is identical to `[Column2] + '%' = [Column1]`. Wildcards are only considered on the right hand side of the expression.

Comment: I just tried it as `'Ashour , Khaled' LIKE [FullName]+'%'` With no luck either :/

Comment: @Kron I see the issue. the `SUBSTRING` was confusing the matter. I've updated my post.

Comment: @Larnu ... oh wow.. yeah works perfect, I feel the fool now for not noticing what was wrong XD

Comment: @Kron you're welcome, sorry for the confusion as well. If the answer i gave works, please do ensure you mark it as the solution so that others can see it was helpful; should they have the same/similar question. Many thanks.